# java.security.KeyStoreException: BKS not found

Tags: jboss, https

I am new to SSL certification generation, I have generated the SSL certification of type BKS. but during the  Jboss starting i am getting the exception: -saying "java.security.KeyStoreException: BKS not found". The below are the steps i am doing to create the keystore file.

keytool -genkey -alias abcd -keystore C:/abcd.keystore  -storepass abcd -storetype BKS -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath c:/bcpkix-jdk15on-147.jar

I am using JBoss 4.2.3 GA.

Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Thank You,
Pruthvi

Answer (score 1):

Error "BKS not found" would mean that its looking for an alias named BKS. Can you pass on the actual error and also the details of the ssl connector definition (server.xml) ?

Comment: Hi, I have used the below configuration in my JBoss server.xml <Connector port="8443" keystorePass="abcd" alias="abcd" keystore="c:/abcd.keystore" keystoreType="BKS" SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" sslImplementationName="org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider"/>

Comment: Couple of suggestions (you will have to try them out)
1. Add the bouncycastle jar file to JAVA_HOME\lib\ext
2. Modify the JAVA_HOME\lib\security\java.security to contain
security.provider.<n>=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
3. Copy bouncycastle jar file to $JBOSS_HOME\server\default\lib 
(default or whatever your instance name is)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you follow these steps

```
http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/3.0.x/ssl-howto.html
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Good point but on the hind sight, if that page is updated, what's copied here is stale and mind you that its not a simple process to just copy the content here.

Comment: yep, but stale information here is better than no information here (which is what will currently happen if the link dies). Only you can decide whether the effort to include the relevant information here is worth it to you or not, but personally I would copy at least a few dot points because with just the link there's a **very** good chance that the answer will become completely worthless in the future.

Comment: @Mac is correct: "...Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer

Comment: I see the point but one could also argue that the relevant parts could get out of sync over time.

Comment: I follow the below tutorial. but still it gives the error: BKS not found. (Key-store file is availble)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the provider into the java.security file as described in [Different types of keystore in Java -- BKS](http://www.pixelstech.net/article/1467528503-Different-types-of-keystore-in-Java----BKS)

> security.provider.N=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider

**N** means the provider index in the provider list.